# Attach VPC endpoint to PRIVATE Rest API with SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I am trying to attach VPC endpoints to my PRIVATE Rest API using AWS SAM. 
I am using [AWS::Serverless::Api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-endpointconfiguration) . I am marking it as private with attribute EndpointConfiguration.

The documentation says it is similar to the EndpointConfiguration of [AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-restapi-endpointconfiguration.html). But it accepts only a string like "PRIVATE" OR "REGIONAL". There is no option to add the vpc endpoints like the cloud formation templates.

```
MyAPI:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
Properties:
  Name: MyAPI
  StageName: prod
  EndpointConfiguration: PRIVATE
  ...
  ...
```

Is there a way to attach the vpc endpoints to APIG with SAM?

Comment: Doesn't look like it's supported in SAM yet. CloudFormation has that option though https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-restapi-endpointconfiguration.html

Answer (score 0):

in the EndpointConfiguration define:

```
EndpointConfiguration:
  Type: PRIVATE
  VPCEndpointIds:
    - vpce-123a123a
    - vpce-321a321a
```